# Why does my array not update after passed in a method that changes its elements?

Tags: java, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I thought arrays are passed by reference - so when I pass str into replaceSpaces, the method returns 'Mr%20John%20Smith' as a char array which is right, but when it returns back to the main method, the char array goes back to its original value of "Mr John Smith    ".

```
public static char[] replaceSpaces(char[] s, int n) {
        String result = "";

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            if(s[i]==' ') {
                result+="%20";
            }
            else {
                result+=s[i];
            }
        }

        s=result.toCharArray();


        return s;
    }

    public static int findLastCharacter(char[] str) {
        for (int i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (str[i] != ' ') {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "Mr John Smith    ";
        char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
        int trueLength = findLastCharacter(arr) + 1;
        replaceSpaces(arr, trueLength); 
        System.out.println("\"" + AssortedMethods.charArrayToString(arr) + "\"");


    }
```

Comment: `char[] replaceSpaces(char[] s, int n)` returns a char array - why not use it?

Comment: To explain why your code is not working as you expect it to: You never change the items within the array. Instead, you change the parameter's reference which will, of course, have no effect on the object passed into the method.

Comment: Use an IDE, it would tell you that the return value is ignored from replaceSpaces(arr, trueLength); and help you find the problem.

Comment: You're using  replaceSpaces(arr, trueLength); as a void method when you've declared it as public static char[] replaceSpaces(char[] s, int n) returning a char[]. You need to edit replaceSpaces to be void and do work on s itself.